# Example of Dijkstra algorithm when source and destination are the same

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

Given the following Directed Weighted Graph, how would it be possible to find the shortest route that both starts and ends in B?

I'm trying Dijkstra and both the situations where the path exists and not exists are running fine, but couldn't find an example to cover the situation I asked above.

[image]

Here's my code, so far

```cs
public static int ShortestDistance(Graph graph, Node from, Node to)
{
    var distances = new Dictionary<Node, int>();
    var actualNodes = graph.GetNodes() as List<Node> ?? Graph.GetNodes().ToList();

    foreach (var node in actualNodes) distances[node] = node.Equals(from) ? 0 : int.MaxValue;

    while (actualNodes.Count() != 0)
    {
        var actualShortest = actualNodes.OrderBy(n => distances[n]).First();
        actualNodes.Remove(actualShortest);

        if (distances[actualShortest] == int.MaxValue) break;

        if (actualShortest.Equals(to)) return distances[actualShortest];

        foreach (var adjacent in graph.GetAdjacentsByNode(actualShortest))
        {
            var actualDistance = distances[actualShortest] + adjacent.Weight;
            if (actualDistance >= distances[adjacent.To]) continue;
            distances[adjacent.To] = actualDistance;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception($"There's no such route from '{from}' to '{to}'.");
}
```

Comment: It's usually a trivial modification to whatever implementation you already have.  You should post your code, or the pseudocode you're following.

Comment: Hi @MattTimmermans, I've edited my post, added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of this algorithm is very slow, but it works.  If you want to search for a >0 path from a node to itself, you can just change your initialization like this:

```
public static int ShortestDistance(Graph graph, Node from, Node to)
{
    var distances = new Dictionary<Node, int>();
    var actualNodes = graph.GetNodes() as List<Node> ?? Graph.GetNodes().ToList();

    foreach (var node in actualNodes) distances[node] = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (var adjacent in graph.GetAdjacentsByNode(from))
    {
        distances[adjacent.To] = adjacent.Weight;
    }

    while (actualNodes.Count() != 0)
    {
        var actualShortest = actualNodes.OrderBy(n => distances[n]).First();
        actualNodes.Remove(actualShortest);

        if (distances[actualShortest] == int.MaxValue) break;

        if (actualShortest.Equals(to)) return distances[actualShortest];

        foreach (var adjacent in graph.GetAdjacentsByNode(actualShortest))
        {
            var actualDistance = distances[actualShortest] + adjacent.Weight;
            if (actualDistance >= distances[adjacent.To]) continue;
            distances[adjacent.To] = actualDistance;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception($"There's no such route from '{from}' to '{to}'.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's like the first time I need to implement such an algorithm, so it's my "brute force" version. :)

If you have some hints, I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: Each call to `actualNodes.OrderBy(n => distances[n]).First();` takes about as long as your entire algorithm should take.  You should really use a proper priority queue instead.  Unfortunately, it seems that .Net, incredibly, does not provide one, so you'd have to make your own for grab one from the web.

Comment: Tell me about it... I also thought about using Priority Queue, but given .NET doesn't implement one by default I just used the OrderBy for this first version.

Answer (score 2):

If zero length route is allowed:

- Then answer is simply 0.

If by route you mean path of length > 0:

- Run Dijkstra from source, get array sp[], such that sp[x] stores
  shortest path from source to x (that's regular usage of Dijkstra)
- Now consider all edges incoming to source.
- Let's say that edge is x -> source with weight of w
- So we can reach source with path > 0 length with total weight of
  sp[x] + w
- Out of all such routes pick minimum one.

Comment: the length is > 0, in this case. For example, fom B->B the result would be 9.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this would be to duplicate (or "shadow") node `B` (call it `BB`), with the same incoming and outgoing edges and weights.

Now, apply Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from `B` to `BB`.  You already have that code in place (i.e. "We have now reduced the problem to something which has previously been solved").

Answer (score 2):

Split the node in two nodes:

- node `S` keeps all outgoing edges
- node `D` keeps all incoming edges

Now solve normally for `S` as source and `D` as destination.